# Эффективные структуры данных для хранения пар ключ-значение

Tags: c++

Поступают данные типа key - value и мне нужно сохранить их для дальнельшей обработки. Только я хочу сохранить их так, чтобы key не повторялись, при этом key может быть любого регистра вплоть до записи типа SoMeKeY.

Как я могу огранизовать данные, чтобы вносить записи максимально быстро и получать доступ к полям также быстро?

Использовать множества думаю не очень подходить, по причине того, что даже если я изменю регистр key на один, то value может быть любым. Соответственно:

```
struct Data {
  string key;
  int value;
}

Data d1;
d1.key = "Tom";
d1.value = 20;
Data d2;
d2.key = "Tom";
d2.value = 35;

Set <Data> a;
a.insert(d1);
a.insert(d2);
```

Все равно добавит запись, хоча key один, но value разные. Также я забыл сказать, что мне нужно будет искать по key без учета value.

Использовать 2 массива также не подходит, потому что мы зарание не знаем сколько у нас будет записей.

Если использовать map, то нужно каждый раз проходить по ему в поисках наличия одинакового key, впрочем это делает и set.

Какое решения на ваш взгляд более оптимальное?

Comment: А что мешает вместо этих структур

     map<string,int>

просто использовать?

Comment: для поиска в map не нужно проходить каждый раз заного, там есть метод find для этого

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вам регистр неважен, тогда используйте map и храните в нем ключи в нижнем регистре. Это и проще и легче. 
Если регистр ключей важен - используйте [кастомный компаратор](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) (специальная функция, которая сравнивает две строки говорит равные или нет) - можно написать свой компаратор, который будет сравнивать две строки без учета регистра. Хотя, думаю, такие уже есть готовые.
[Пример хитрого компаратора](http://cnx.org/content/m35767/latest/) для "мультиключа".

Еще один вариант:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, int>> data;
```

как ключ - храните ключ в нижнем регистре. в pair первым параметром храните ключ в как он предоставлен, второй параметр - собственно значение. Памяти это будет потреблять больше, но скорость будет вполне приличная.